# Eloquent 5.5 paginate() not working outside laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5, illuminate-container

I am using Illuminate/database package outside Laravel with my CodeIgniter setup. The initialization is done using `Capsule` class like this

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as CapsuleManager;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;

class Capsule extends CapsuleManager
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    require_once __DIR__.'/../config/database.php';
    $db = (object) $db['default'];

    $this->addConnection(array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => $db->hostname,
        'database'  => $db->database,
        'username'  => $db->username,
        'password'  => $db->password,
        'charset'   => $db->char_set,
        'collation' => $db->dbcollat,
        'prefix'    => $db->dbprefix,
    ));

    $this->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

    // Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
    $this->setAsGlobal();

    // Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
    $this->bootEloquent();
}
}
```

I had it running on `illuminate/database` 5.2. Recently I updated it to `illuminate/database` 5.5. My Eloquent paginate() has stopped working. The links() method on eloquent collection gives following error.

```
Call to a member function make() on null
```

With a stack trace to

```
return new HtmlString(static::viewFactory()->make($view ?: static::$defaultView, array_merge($data, [
```

in `vendor\illuminate\pagination\LengthAwarePaginator.php` on Line 90

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show your html where you used links()